# XRegExp replace cannot get match string

Tags: replace, xregexp

```
var name = XRegExp('(?<first>\\w+) (?<last>\\w+)','g');
var strNew=XRegExp.replace('John Smith', name, '${last}, ${first}');//->John Smith
```

why strNew is "John Smith" not "Smith,John"????

Answer (score 0):

It works for me...check you've properly installed XRegExp and are printing out `strNew` and not `name`

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title></title> <meta charset="utf-8"> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/xregexp-min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> var name = XRegExp('(?<first>\\w+) (?<last>\\w+)','g'); var strNew=XRegExp.replace('John Smith', name, '${last}, ${first}'); console.log(strNew) </script> </head> <body> </body> </html>